# What's a regex to stitch everything inside []?

Tags: java, regex

I have text annotated with linguistic tags as follows:

```
PRE[per]    ART[la] NOUN[creazione] PRE[di] ART[un] NOUN[prodotto]  ADJ[innovativo]     ARTPRE[nel] NOUN[mercato]   ARTPRE[delle]   NOUN[comunicazioni] PRE[senza]  NOUN[fili] PUN[(]   NPR[WiFi]   PUN[)]
```

What regex will give me back the text inside the square brackets, spaced as one match? That is:

```
per la creazione di un prodotto innovativo nel mercato delle comunicazioni senza fili (WiFi)
```

Comment: Why does this have a java tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work by matching whatever is inside [], although the () will also be spaced:

```
str.replaceAll(".*?\\[(.*?)\\]", "$1 "));
```

Comment: `str.replaceAll(".*?\\[(.*?)\\]","$1 ")` is enough.

Comment: or faster still: `[^\\[]*\\[([^\\]]*)\\]`

Answer (score 2):

You need a regular expression and a loop that concatenates all matches.

Since you have applied the Java tag, the Java code for that is:

```
    String text = ...;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(text);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.append(matcher.group(1));
        result.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "PRE[per]    ART[la] NOUN[creazione] PRE[di] ART[un] NOUN[prodotto]  ADJ[innovativo]     ARTPRE[nel] NOUN[mercato]   ARTPRE[delle]   NOUN[comunicazioni] PRE[senza]  NOUN[fili] PUN[(]   NPR[WiFi]   PUN[)] ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[(\\w+)\\])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(matcher.find()) {
    sb.append(matcher.group(2)).append(" ");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```